# Changing countdown duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-countdown

I use this countdown on my website, [**here**](http://johns-webdesign.com/client/bobbie/video/index.php)

You can view the script [**here**](http://johns-webdesign.com/client/bobbie/video/javascripts/jquery.countdown.js) (Too large to post)

This is the code in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var austDay = new Date();
            austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
            $('.countdown-container').countdown({until: austDay});
            $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
        });
    </script>
```

I want to be able to change the countdown duration, hopefully to what ever time I want.

If anyone could lend an insight then that would be fantastic.

Comment: I have tried changing this part:

this._defaults = {
  until: '30D', // new Date(year, mth - 1, day, hr, min, sec) - date/time to count down to
   // or numeric for seconds offset, or string for unit offset(s):
   // 'Y' years, 'O' months, 'W' weeks, 'D' days, 'H' hours, 'M' minutes, 'S' seconds

It originally pointed to "NULL". I am quite sure that I am on the right tracks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the zip package that you have bought from Themeforest does have the information on how to change the countdown information, I'm also pretty sure that you can contact the author http://www.avathemes.com/HTML5/Paris/

Comment: You should post the **relevant** HTML output, and Scripts. Posting just the links makes this question useless to any other user with a similar issue in the future when the links are dead. Please also post any script changes you have already tried so others don't re-do the same solution assuming it will work.

Comment: the HTML is just a div holder, nothing really useful. I have contacted the author Torm, thought I would try and help some help as well. I have knowledge in PHP, but not a lot with JavaScript / jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

```
var CommingDate = new Date(); 
CommingDate= new Date(CommingDate.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
```

explanation

`Date(`**CommingDate.getFullYear() + 1**`, 1 - 1, 26);`
means that you want to get the current year an increase it by 1

`Date(CommingDate.getFullYear() + 1,` **1 - 1**`, 26);`

the first number will go forwards a month , so if you were to do `2 - 1` the month will be Feb

but if you were to do something like `1 - 1` this will result in getting the current month
`Date(CommingDate.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1,` **26**`);`
the last number 26 will be the day that you want

Comment: I'm not asking people to do my work by the way. That was already in the head section as well.

Comment: then what do you want to accomplish , what time do you want to show

Comment: I guess I just want to figure out how to change it, perhaps if I got an example of say, 30 days then I would, from there, have the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same questions but Hussein's explanation help me solve it.

For example if you want to countdown to 25.10.2017 the code should be

```
Date(CommingDate.getFullYear() + 1, 10 - 1, 25);
```

where

**CommingDate.getFullYear() + 1** - *it's 2017 (actual year + 1)*

**10 - 1** - *it's the month*

**25** - *it's the day*